# Quickly format all columns in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, formatting

I have a gridview with a lot of columns, and I wanted them formatted the same way (easy stuff, like ItemStyle="solid").

Is there a quick way to apply the same itemstyle, etc. to all columns in a gridview?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The Grid uses Table elements.  Datafields are td and headers and footers are th.  So you can define a css class with the table elements and call the CSS Class.  Alternately you can use the ItemStyle and AlternatingItemStyle properties of the Gridview.